# Django template comparing strings returning false?

Tags: django, templates

I have in my template a button that should only be visible if

1 The user is signed in and;
2 The user is the one who posted the listing

but doesnt show up even if all the above conditions have been met,
so i have this in my template:

```
{% if user.username == "{{ users }}" %}
    <form action="listing" method="GET">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Close Listing" name="close">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

where "{{users}}" is the username of whoever posted the listing, and thus if its a match, this user gets the button

**views.py**

```
listing = Listing.objects.all().filter(title=title).first()
user = listing.user
```

**passing it to the template:**

```
return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
     "users": user
})
```

Cant find what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic;

First:

```
listing = Listing.objects.all().filter(title=title).first()

# Change variable name, you should name your variables with their purpose
author = listing.user

return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
     "author": author
})
```

Second:

```
# No need to use {{ }} in condition because `Jinja` does it for you.
{% if request.user == author %} # {% if request.user.username == author.username %}
    <form action="listing" method="GET">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Close Listing" name="close">
    </form>
{% endif %}
```